# GUI With Thread Losing Focus in Windows

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I am trying to update a `textctrl` in wxpython while a long running thread is finding some sort of information. It works well until the user changes focus to another window, and then upon returning to the wxpython script, the GUI is unresponsive until the thread is finished.

Is there a way to return to this script and still see the `textctrl` updating with the animated cursor?

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
import thread
import Queue
from time import sleep

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

        def __init__( self, parent ):
                wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

                self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

                bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

                self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

                self.m_button1 = wx.Button( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                bSizer2.Add( self.m_button1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

                self.m_panel1.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
                self.m_panel1.Layout()
                bSizer2.Fit( self.m_panel1 )
                bSizer1.Add( self.m_panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

                self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

                self.m_textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_MULTILINE )
                bSizer3.Add( self.m_textCtrl1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

                self.m_panel2.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
                self.m_panel2.Layout()
                bSizer3.Fit( self.m_panel2 )
                bSizer1.Add( self.m_panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

                self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
                self.Layout()

                self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

                # Connect Events
                self.m_button1.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.do_something )

        def __del__( self ):
                pass


        # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
        def do_something( self, event ):
                event.Skip()



class MyFrame( MyFrame1 ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        MyFrame1.__init__( self, parent )

    def do_something(self, event):
        self.Result = Queue.Queue()
        thread.start_new_thread(self.do_loop, ())
        self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText("searching for something... ")
        self.found= 0
        for character in self.cursor():
            self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText(character)
            self.Update()
            sleep(0.1)
            self.m_textCtrl1.Undo()
            if (self.found == 1):
                self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText('\n')
                break
        num = self.Result.get()
        print num

    def cursor(self):
        characters='.oOo'
        i = 0
        while 1:
            yield characters[i]
            i = (i + 1) % len(characters)

    def do_loop(self):
        x = 0
        while (x < 20007):
            print x
            x = x + 1
            if x == 20000:
                self.Result.put(x)
                self.found = 1
                break

class threadtest(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.m_frame = MyFrame(None)
        self.m_frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.m_frame)
        return True

app = threadtest(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The loop in MyFrame.do_something() is blocking the event loop.

Comment: Ah, ok, so if I put the animated cursor into another thread, that should unblock the button event. I will play around with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on Anonymous Coward's comment. I moved everything from the button event into a thread. Let me know if there is a better way to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
import thread
import Queue
from time import sleep

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

        def __init__( self, parent ):
                wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

                self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

                bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

                self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

                self.m_button1 = wx.Button( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                bSizer2.Add( self.m_button1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

                self.m_panel1.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
                self.m_panel1.Layout()
                bSizer2.Fit( self.m_panel1 )
                bSizer1.Add( self.m_panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

                self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

                self.m_textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_MULTILINE )
                bSizer3.Add( self.m_textCtrl1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

                self.m_panel2.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
                self.m_panel2.Layout()
                bSizer3.Fit( self.m_panel2 )
                bSizer1.Add( self.m_panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

                self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
                self.Layout()

                self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

                # Connect Events
                self.m_button1.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.do_something )

        def __del__( self ):
                pass


        # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
        def do_something( self, event ):
                event.Skip()



class MyFrame( MyFrame1 ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        MyFrame1.__init__( self, parent )

    def do_something(self, event):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.do_something_thread, ())

    def do_something_thread(self):
        self.Result = Queue.Queue()
        thread.start_new_thread(self.do_loop, ())
        self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText("searching for something... ")
        self.found= 0
        for character in self.cursor():
            self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText(character)
            self.Update()
            sleep(0.1)
            self.m_textCtrl1.Undo()
            if (self.found == 1):
                self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText('\n')
                break
        num = self.Result.get()
        print num

    def cursor(self):
        characters='.oOo'
        i = 0
        while 1:
            yield characters[i]
            i = (i + 1) % len(characters)

    def do_loop(self):
        x = 0
        while (x < 20007):
            print x
            x = x + 1
            if x == 20000:
                self.Result.put(x)
                self.found = 1
                break

class threadtest(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.m_frame = MyFrame(None)
        self.m_frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.m_frame)
        return True

app = threadtest(0)
app.MainLoop()
```